# Insert all HTML form fields (filled and empty) to array php

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I have a large HTML form where I currently insert filled html fields into and array. When I print out my `$_POST['rep_list'];` it gives me the keys and values filled out from the form. But what I need is an array with **all** form fields (***even the ones not filled out***).
 
Any suggestion/examples on how to achieve this?

```
    <form action="insert-data.php" name="workCard" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
    <legend><h3>Repair</h3></legend>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Front</th>
        <th>Back</th>       
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>tire</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_list[tire_front]" value="tire_front" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_list[tire_back]" value="tire_back" /></td>
        <td>alm <input type="checkbox" name="rep_list[tire_reg]" value="tire_reg" /></td>
        <td>indl <input type="checkbox" name="rep_list[tire_indl]" value="tire_indl" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Tube</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_list[tube_front]" value="tube_front" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_list[tube_back]" value="tube_back" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hub.rep.</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_list[hub_front]" value="hub_front" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_list[hub_back]" value="hub_back" /></td>
        <td>just. <input type="checkbox" name="rep_list[hub_adjust]" value="hub_adjust" /></td>
 etc…....
```

Comment: Just create an array, containing all the names of the html items you declared, loop over it and check if value isset or not, and create an array..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without javascript you can create text input's for all checkboxes. For example:

```
<td>
    <input type="hidden" name="rep_list[tire_front]" value="False" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="rep_list[tire_front]" value="True" />
</td>
```

When you check the `POST` in PHP you can determine if a checkbox is checked or not by checking the value .When the `POST` value is `True` the checkbox was checked and `False` is unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

With checkboxes if they are ticked they will be set in the HTTP post with their given value (or default of 'on' if a value is not set). If they are not ticked no value will be sent.

To check if a checkbox was ticked in PHP you could simply check if a POST value was set:

```
$tire_front = isset($_POST['rep_list']['tire_front']);
```

If you wanted to do this for every item you could create an array of the keys and loop through each of these:

```
$fields = array(
    'tire_front',
    'tire_back',
    'tire_reg',
    'tire_indl',
    'tube_front',
    'tube_back',
    'hub_front',
    'hub_back',
    'hub_adjust'
);

foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $rep_list[$field] = isset($_POST['rep_list'][$field]);
}
```

`$rep_list` would then contain an entry for each of the fields with a value of `true` if ticked, or `false` if not.